# access remote mysql server through socks proxy server

Tags: linux, mysql, port-forwarding

Scenario:
A - Local Unix machine
B - socks proxy server port 1080
C - remote mysql server port 3306

I want to connect to the remote mysql server(C) from local unix machine(A) using sock proxy(B). Please could anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use putty from the local machine, conncet with ssh to your server, set up a SSH tunnel to port forward localhost:3306
then connect the mysql client on your local machine to localhost:9999

Putty setup:
SSH-Tunnels -> Local -> Source port: 9999 ->Destination: localhost:3306

Comment: Unfortunately this answer uses port forwarding instead of a SOCKS proxy :-(